# Python Inheritance Hierarchy Confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Case 1:

```
class Hexagon():
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.points = 6
        self.angle = (360 / self.points)


class Polygon(Hexagon):
    def __init__(self, radius, points):
        Hexagon.__init__(self, radius)
        self.points = points


p1 = Polygon(125, 8)
print(p1.angle)
```

Case 2:

```
class Hexagon():
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.points = 6
        self.angle = (360 / self.points)


class Polygon(Hexagon):
    def __init__(self, radius, points):
        Hexagon.__init__(self, radius)
        self.points = points
        self.angle = (360 / self.points)


p1 = Polygon(125, 8)
print(p1.angle)
```

I have 2 set of code stated above. for #Case 1 it printed 60, for #Case 2 it printed 45. Why for Case 1 under the angle attribute expression, python get the self.point value from the parents class which is predefine 6, instead of the value from the child class, which is 8? isn't it based on Inheritance Hierarchy python will search the attribute in child class, then parents class. Once it find the attribute in child class, it will take that as the value and stop searching?

Instead I have to override the self.angle attribute in the child class like in Case 2 to get the value that I want. which is 360/8 = 45.

Comment: Your hierarchy is backwards.  A Hexagon is a type of Polygon, not vice versa.

Comment: You did `self.angle = (360 / self.points)` *immediately after* doing `self.points = 6`, so 6 is the value that was used in that calculation.  `self.angle` isn't going to magically change later when `self.points` is assigned a value of 8.